# Is it possible to take a list of functions and return a function which is their composite

Tags: haskell

I was trying to figure out how to do something along the lines of

```
compositeFunctions :: [(a -> a)] -> (a -> a)
```

I was thinking I could use `foldr` to continuously fold the list of functions over, but I can't figure anything out.

Comment: You're on the right track!  consider `foldr :: (x -> y -> x) -> x -> [y] -> x`, now substitute `a -> a` for `y`. What does `x` need to be? What's a good default value for the parameter of type `x`? What would the value of type `x -> y -> x` need to do?

Comment: `foldMap` (as in `compositeFunctions = appEndo . foldMap Endo`) conveys the _intent_ better than `foldr` I think. (And is only a handful of characters longer than `foldr (.) id`)

Comment: Using `foldMap` is very obscure, imo.

Answer (score 11):

`foldr` does exactly what you want, since `id` is the identity for `(.)` (i.e., `f . id == f`):

```
compose :: [(a -> a)] -> a -> a
compose = foldr (.) id
```

In a more explicit recursive form:

```
compose' [] = id
compose' (f:fs) = f . compose' fs
```

Answer (score 8):

Functions of the form `a -> a`, i.e. the argument and result have the same type, are known as *endomorphisms*. A really cool thing about endomorphisms for a given `a` is that they form a monoid with `id` as the identity and `(.)` as the operator. This means that `mconcat` should do exactly what you want...

```
compositeFunctions = mconcat
```

...unfortunately it's slightly more complicated. In order to get at the `Monoid` instance, you'll have to wrap your functions in the `Endo` newtype from `Data.Monoid` and then unwrap the result:

```
compositeFunctions = appEndo . mconcat . fmap Endo
```

Comment: Or more succinctly `compositeFunctions = appEndo . foldMap Endo`, as I mentioned in my comment.

Comment: You could also use the reducers package, it becomes something like `reduceWith appEndo`.

Comment: Why doesn't `(a -> a)` just have a Monoid instance itself? Why is using a newtype necessary?

Comment: Because the function arrow also admits the similarly useful `instance Monoid m => Monoid (r -> m)`.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner That is one of the least known yet most useful instances of `Monoid`. I wish it were more advertised. :/